# In the below given sentence I want to know what role is played by the word running ?How does it fit in a sentence pattern?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Thomas came running.

In the above sentence THOMAS is the subject and CAME is the verb. What grammatical label can be given to the word RUNNING.

Answer (score 1):

That's a participle adverbial phrase.

Answer (score 0):

> *Thomas came running.*

"Come" is a catenative verb, so this is a catenative construction.

"Running" is a non-finite clause serving as catenative **complement** of "came".

The term "catenative" comes from the Latin word for "chain". We use it to describe constructions which have a chain of two or more verbs, like "came" and "running" in your example.